# How to disable a part of GUI

Tags: java, android

I have a form in my app. I want only the admin have the right to edit the form. What should I do?

```
nameET = (EditText) mForm.findViewById(R.id.nameET);
descET = (EditText) mForm.findViewById(R.id.descET);
```

Comment: Don't make it an `EditText`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `setEnabled(false)` to disable the `EditText`s.

```
if (!admin) {
    nameET.setEnabled(false);
    descET.setEnabled(false);
}
```